# ILE RPG Static SQL Fetch first row of a cursor

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400, rpgle

My Code:

```
     EXEC SQL
     DECLARE C1 CURSOR
     FOR SELECT * FROM a
     WHERE :field LIKE CONCAT(TRIM(a.number), '%')
     ORDER BY a.number DESC;

     EXEC SQL
     OPEN C1;

     EXEC SQL
     FETCH C1 INTO :a;
```

I need only the highest number of the cursor - so the ORDER BY DESC.

How can I fetch only the first row of the cursor C1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 EXEC SQL
     FETCH C1 INTO :a;
```

Only fetches one row...so just execute it a single time.

However, you'd be better off using a `SELECT INTO` with `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY` if you know you only need 1 row

```
exec sql
  SELECT * 
    FROM a
    INTO :a
   WHERE :field LIKE CONCAT(TRIM(a.number), '%')
   ORDER BY a.number DESC
   FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

Comment: big thanks! It worked perfect, code is also smarter and easy to read.